# Yii2 show name instead of id (customer_id) in error message

Tags: php, yii2

i want to show customer name instead of customer id in error message.

How to achieve this?

Below is the relation in my model,

```
public function getCustomer() {
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ["id" => "customer_id"]);
}
```

Model Validation Rules, here in error message i have to set customer name,

```
public function rules()
        {
            return [         
                ['customer_id','unique','message'=>'Customer **{here i have to set customer name}** already exist in rd pool'],

            ];
        }
```

[image]

Comment: show the related  code ..

Comment: Assumption : your relation name `customer`. Try Customer `$this->customer->name` has already been taken.

Comment: @InsaneSkull you're right, we can get customer name this way but when i have tried this in error messgae then i didn't get customer name. Please check, i have added my validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

Use costume validation for this propose

first in rule function of models class declare costume validation function

```
return [

        ['id', 'validateID', 'when'=> function($model){
                return (!empty($model->id))? true:false;
            },],
        ......
];
```

Then in the same model create public function called validateId

```
public function validateId($attribute, $params, $validator)
{
    $id = $this->id;

   { here you can write code to check}
    if(condition check)){
        $this->addError('id', "Coustumer $userName booking start date");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then add 'enableAjaxValidation' => True,  In form

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true
    ]); ?>
```

At last in Controller check validation of model like

```
if($request->isAjax && $model->load($request->post())){
        yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
```

If you have some confusion Please refer

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators

Comment: Yes i can create custom validator but i think i is common requirement so yii had deplevoded. but i don't know i to do it